# LsaLogonUserで取得したtokenからGetTokenInformationを実行すると、x64でビルドした場合にユーザーのSIDが取得できない

Tags: c#

secur32.dllのLsaLogonUserを利用してログイン認証を行っています。
LsaLogonUserの戻り値がSTATUS_SUCCESS(0)になっているにも関わらず、取得したtokenからGetTokenInformationを実行すると「ハンドルが無効です。」のエラーになってしまい、ユーザー情報が取得できません（ユーザーのSIDを取得したいです）。

ただ、このコードをx86でビルドした場合には取得することができます。
x64だと取得に失敗する理由が分かりませんでした。
すみませんが、ご教示頂ければと思います。

なお、取得されるtokenはx86の場合は「0x00000b80」や「0x00000a4c」になるのに対し、x64の場合は常に「0x0000000005410001」が返ってきます。

末尾の行のGetTokenInformationのResultがfalseになり、Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()を呼び出すと6（ハンドルが無効です。）になります。

以下、関連する部分を抜粋します。

```
        private bool CheckLoginUser(uint authPackage, IntPtr outCredBuffer, uint outCredSize)
        {
            const string PG_NAME = "Sample";

            WinStatusCodes status = LsaConnectUntrusted(out IntPtr lsaHandle);
            if (status != WinStatusCodes.STATUS_SUCCESS) return false;

            using (LsaStringWrapper originName = new LsaStringWrapper(PG_NAME))
            {
                //ログイン試行実施
                TOKEN_SOURCE source = new TOKEN_SOURCE(PG_NAME);
                status = LsaLogonUser(lsaHandle, ref originName._string, SecurityLogonType.Interactive,
                                      authPackage, outCredBuffer, outCredSize, IntPtr.Zero, ref source, out IntPtr profileBuffer,
                                      out uint profileBufferLength, out long logonId, out IntPtr token, out QUOTA_LIMITS quotas, out WinStatusCodes subStatus);

                //ログインに失敗すると1326が返る
                var ntStatus = LsaNtStatusToWinError((uint)status);
                Console.WriteLine("ntStatus: " + ntStatus);

                if (profileBuffer != IntPtr.Zero) LsaFreeReturnBuffer(profileBuffer);

                //ユーザー認証失敗（戻り値が成功でない）
                if (status != WinStatusCodes.STATUS_SUCCESS) return false;  //パスワードを間違えると、STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE（3221225581 = 0xC000006D）が返る

                //tokenからユーザー情報を取得
                int TokenInfLength = 0;
                // first call gets lenght of TokenInformation
                bool Result = GetTokenInformation(token, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenUser, IntPtr.Zero, TokenInfLength, out TokenInfLength);
                IntPtr TokenInformation = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(TokenInfLength);
                Result = GetTokenInformation(token, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenUser, TokenInformation, TokenInfLength, out TokenInfLength);
```

Comment: 必要とする機能・情報によっては.NET APIを使った方が良いのでは？ [System.Security.Principal 名前空間](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.security.principal?view=net-6.0), [WindowsIdentity クラス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity?view=net-6.0), [WindowsIdentity(String)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.-ctor?view=net-6.0#System_Security_Principal_WindowsIdentity__ctor_System_String_), [WindowsIdentity.User](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.user?view=net-6.0)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。助かります。
LsaLogonUserで取得したtokenを、WindowsIdentityに渡したらSIDを取得できました。
次のコードです。
'''
                var safeIntPtr = new SafeAccessTokenHandle(token);

                var loginUserSid = "";
                WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(safeIntPtr, () =>
                {
                    loginUserSid = new WindowsIdentity(token).User.Value;
                });
'''

何故x64のときにはこのようにしなければならないのかが分からないままなのですが、何かご存じでしょうか。

Comment: 私には分かりませんが、この辺のソースコードの関連部分を調べてみてはどうでしょう？ [microsoft/referencesource](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource), [dotnet/standard](https://github.com/dotnet/standard)

Comment: ありがとうございます。頂いたソースの部分も確認してみたのですが、特に新しい発見はありませんでした。
どうも、上記のコードを記載するとLsaLogonUserのtokenの戻り値自体が変わります（追加した部分ではなく、元々記載していたLsaLogonUserの呼び出し結果が変わる）。
また、同じく上記コードを別メソッドに分けたところ、LsaLogonUserのtokenが「0x0000000005410001」固定に戻ってしまいました。
ですので、PInvokeの問題のような気がしてきています。
すみませんが、気になる点がございましたらアドバイス頂ければと思います。